# Renew vault token

Tags: vault

I created vault token with the following settings:

```
vault write sys/auth/token/tune max_lease_ttl=9000h
vault write sys/auth/token/tune default_lease_ttl=9000h
vault token create -policy=spring_cloud
```

[image]

```
Key                  Value
---                  -----
accessor             N4PBquNCvIhTLXLYiVQG235g
creation_time        1683705437
creation_ttl         9000h
display_name         token
entity_id            n/a
expire_time          2024-05-19T07:57:17.65597752Z
explicit_max_ttl     0s
id                   xxxx
issue_time           2023-05-10T07:57:17.610332378Z
last_renewal         2023-12-01T15:11:51.655977681Z
last_renewal_time    1701443511
meta                 <nil>
num_uses             0
orphan               false
path                 auth/token/create
policies             [default spring_cloud]
renewable            true
ttl                  4072h36m49s
type                 service
```

I'm trying to renew vault token with the following command

```
vault token renew -increment=9000h
```

And got the following warning:

```
* TTL of "9000h" exceeded the effective max_ttl of "4072h45m26s"; TTL value
  is capped accordingly
```

As i understand, the result must be the following: increment 9000h starts from the last_renewal date(2023-12-01T15:11:51.655977681Z), so expire_time and ttl must increase. Instead of this, we have expire_time which is not increasing = it's always  9000h from the issue_time date. And ttl also doesn't increase. Only decreasing. Vault version: v1.10.3